# Tracking Facebook App Installs within an Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on an Ionic (cordova) app and I am looking into options to track app installs from a Facebook mobile app install campaign. The facebook-cordova plugin (https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) looks promising but other than a claim that app activations are automatically tracked, I am not sure how to proceed. I assume that there is more to it than simply dropping in the plugin, I must have to initialize something somewhere, I would think.

In addition, I am looking for guidance on how to test this before deploying.

I would love to hear specifics from anyone who has solved this problem, either with this plugin or through some other means.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user logs in with Facebook, it automatically tracks with Facebook's analytics, you don't need to do any kind of setting!

I have used the same git repo as you and it is working perfectly.

Comment: No dude, i have installed it in my code but its not working

Comment: Ok, but how can u make a connection between App installs/Facebook logins and Ad Campaigns in Facebook Ads Manager? So that you’d track App Installs in each campaign automatically, and so that correct app installs would be attributed to the right ad campaign?